# how to access my database in cpanel server?

Tags: php, mysql

The following error occur for my website:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'mydb_db'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) in
>   /home/fiveghr/public_html/don/dbconnection/connection.php on line 8
>   Could not connect: Access denied for user 'mydb_db'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

```
<?php
$rpath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
require $rpath."/don/dbconnection/config.php"; 
class getdbconnection {
    public function getConnection(){
        //      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","*****","******");
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        if (!$con)
        {
            return die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            //          mysql_select_db("real_state", $con);
            mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);
            //return $con;
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: You should find as mysql in your cpanel, there you shall create the db, username and password

Comment: you should never share your database password online. Please try to use ***** in place of password

Comment: but i want to know how to solve this issue..?

Comment: Did you create this database and user already?

Comment: yes my website working already for last 2 yrs without any problem but now unfortunately this error occurs@RST

Comment: If it suddenly stopped working, you may need to contact your host. Maybe they updated something, PHP for instance.

Comment: Try replacing all mysql... with mysqli_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `DB_HOST`
must be the server address as `"http://www.myserver.com"` not localhost

Comment: but the error clearly shows that he is accessing the localhost

Comment: Take a look at the default WordPress config file.